# How do get audience peak based on daterange on a single mysql table?

Tags: mysql, datetime, streaming, analytics, audience

I have one MySQL table that register the start end end streaming time of an live webinar to an specific user/course with this schema:

> ID (int 11) | userID (int 11) | courseID (int 11) | streamStart (datetime) | streamEnd (datetime)
>
> Here are some rows for example:
>
> 1 ----------------    1409 ----------------   189 -----------   2015-08-20 20:15:15    ----    2015-08-20 21:00:00
>
> 2 ----------------    1423 ----------------   190 -----------   2015-08-23 20:10:03    ----    2015-08-23 22:00:00
>
> 3 ----------------    1408 ----------------   189 -----------   2015-08-20 20:45:03    ----    2015-08-20 21:15:00

where streamStart is the datetime where user start to watch and streamEnd is the datetime that user quit the live streaming session.

I want to know using just MySQL, what was the audience peak for courseID 189 (max number of concurrent users) using this data. Is it possible? How?

Extra challenge (optional): If you can help me with that, is there a way to tell what time that the peak occurred?

Comment: There is a way to do both, and the bonus question must be processed to calculate the first question. 

There is no minimum time taken into consideration, correct?

Comment: Correct! Just the daterange intersection peak.

Comment: Looking forward for your solution!

Comment: Still looking for help!